# Mysql query, item contains all specified tags

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table of items, table of tags and a table which connects these two (many-to-many).

```
Fields of each table:
 items:
    id_item INT

 tags:
    id_tag INT

 item_tag:
    id_item INT
    id_tag INT
```

Now each item can have one or more tags. I want to perform a tag based search which will select only these items which contain the specified tags. So if I have item with tags `FLASH (id=1), PHP(id=2), MYSQL(id=3), RAGE(id=4)` I can find it when searching for:

```
FLASH, [1] (This is an array of tag ID's)
FLASH + PHP, [1,2]
MYSQL + PHP + RAGE, [3,2,4]
PHP + FLASH + MYSQL + RAGE [2,1,3,4]
```

but it should be found when I am looking for, eg:

```
ACTIONSCRIPT, [8]
PHP + ACTIONSCRIPT, [2,8]
```

I thought about using simple LEFT JOIN with IN(...) but then I realized it wouldn't work... Any hints? Can it be done just via Mysql query without manually parsing the data in PHP?

### UPDATE:

Taking into consideration answer by Brad Christie, here is an example query with the question being asked:

```
SELECT t1.some_field, GROUP_CONCAT(t2.id_tag ORDER BY t2.id_tag) AS tagList FROM items t1
LEFT JOIN item_tag t2 ON t1.id_item = t2.id_item
WHERE HERE_LIES_THE_PROBLEM
```

Now, where we have **HERE_LIES_THE_PROBLEM** should be a function which checks if all elements presented in *X* are in *tagList*. So if *tagList* is "1,2,3,4" and *X* is "1,2" it should work, but if *X* is (1,2,5) it shouldn't. How to do this part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does [this previous SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/167067/mysql-limit-with-many-to-many-relationship) help out at all?

**EDIT**

Also, what's wrong with concatenating the query in PHP and using `AND` to include all search terms?

**EDITV2**

Excuse the fact that I'm doing this on the phone. As I said, ill post a better solution when I have an opportunity. But something like the following, though long, should work:

```
SELECT *
FROM items
WHERE id_item IN (
  SELECT item_tag.id_item
  FROM item_tag
    INNER JOIN tags
    ON tags.id_tag = item_tag.id_tag
  WHERE tags.tag_name='PHP'
  )
  AND id_item IN (
    --- same as above, just different tag
  )
```

Only problem is it's long and inefficient. Like I said, when I'm not on a phone ill make improvements.

Comment: Well this group_concat() certainly solves one thing. But then, it will return (for the example given): (1,2,3,4). If I have a list of ID's of tags to look for, say (4,2) how can I check if ALL of its elements are in the (1,2,3,4)? I am not sure how your second question relates to my problem though, the search-for tags are/can be concatenated via PHP (that's why I thought about using IN).

Comment: I still say building your query and concatenating with each tag that you need to compare is your best bet. Use a `select item where I'd_item in (<select tags but make inclusive to all items>)` When I'm not at a coffee shop ill update my answer.

Comment: Oh man, I think I simply don't understand what you mean here, may be the late hour (1 AM) or my not too high knowledge of SQL stuff. I can build/generate query differently depending on the tag, but anyway if you can please provide an example I'd be really grateful, it's a real pain for me this problem, and the only solution I can think of is to get all items and then iterate over each of them in PHP and remove accordingly.

Comment: Ok, thanks to your link I realised what to search for and found this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3192416/will-this-normalised-database-structure-permit-me-to-search-by-tags-as-i-intend which is exactly what I needed :).